# My modem is conneting to the internet but will not connect to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

Hardware:

- Modem: Arris Surfboard SB8200
- Router: TPlink Archer ax3000 pro hardware v1.60 (router is only around a month or two old)

All the lights are on correctly for the modem so I try to plug the ethernet cable into the router I check the activity light and there is nothing then I plug the same cable directly to my PC I can access the internet.

Router has three lights on power, 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands while it has 3 lights off.

Internet USB and ethernet can connect to router through Wi-Fi but not ethernet not showing up as a device through the computer.

This router did work in the past but just happened around a day or two ago.

Does the router need a firmware update? Or do I need to replace the router? What could be wrong here?

Comment: I'd probably start by checking if the router works 'on its own' without being connected to the internet. Can you connect to wifi or a wired connection and access the router's management page to start with?

Comment: Hm, is the router dead? Could be the power brick - did it work before and any changes in setup?

Comment: “…so I try to plug the ethernet cable into the router I check the activity light and there is nothing…” Are you plugging the Ethernet cable from the modem into the WAN port on the router? Does the router even power up? Any lights on it?

Comment: `All the lights are on correctly for the modem` - what lights are on on the router? Has the router worked in the past? Is this a brand new purchase?

Comment: So basically the first three lights indicating power, 2.4 and 5ghz are on for the router

Comment: I can connect to the router through wifi but can't through ethernet

Comment: This router did work in the past but just happened around a day or two ago

Comment: Maybe the cable is bad, try another. And through wifi, can you access the router's web management interface? You should be able to reach the router through an ethernet port (not the wan port) too